# Get column index matching the date value in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2003

Below the screenshot/formula I am trying to match the date value in Column E against another date range column in Column B.
If found, then return column D's matching value.

```
FORMULA: ==LOOKUP(E3,$A$3:$B$46,$C$3:$C$46)

Current Output:

FROM    TO      AGE(Years)  INPUT   OUTPUT
7/4/65  10/4/65 0.25        7/4/68  0.25

Expected Output:

FROM    TO      AGE(Years)  INPUT   OUTPUT
7/4/65  10/4/65 0.25        1/4/68  **2.75**
```

NOTE: I am using **EXCEL 2003**!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use index/match to get the value in column D corresponding to the match position in column E:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(D$3:D$46,MATCH(E3,$B$3:$B$46,0)),"No")
```

However, according to [this](https://www.excelfunctions.net/excel-2003-vs-excel-2007.html) Iferror wasn't available until Excel 2007 so you'd have to use Iserror or Isna:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(D3,$B$3:$B$46,0)),"No",INDEX(C$3:C$46,MATCH(D3,$B$3:$B$46,0)))
```

For the date *ranges*

If you decide to use Vlookup:

```
=VLOOKUP(D3,A$3:C$46,3,TRUE)
```

Or the two versions of Lookup:

```
=LOOKUP(D3,A$3:C$46)

=LOOKUP(D3,A$3:A$46,C$3:C$46)
```

all give the same results.

[image]

Note that I am doing the lookup on column A and it doesn't give the same answer as an exact lookup on column B. This is because it's not clear whether 10/4/65 (for example) should produce .25 or .5 because both are possible as 10/4/65 is the end of one range and the start of another and I have chosen to go for the second one.

---

**Extra challenge**

Would it be fairly easy to do this without doing a lookup and just using Excel 2003 functions?

Yes. If A1 contains the baseline date (maybe a date of birth) 4/4/65, it would look like this:

```
=YEAR(D3)-YEAR(A$1)+INT((MONTH(D3)-MONTH(A$1)-(DAY(D3)<DAY(A$1)))/3)/4
```

Comment: Another change to the condition, instead of adding NO I want to check if the INPUT date is within the range and get the index value.
I tried to add the condition =IF(AND(E3>A3, E3<B2)) instead of MATCH. I am getting spillover errors.

Comment: =LOOKUP(F3,$A$3:$B$46,$C$3:$C$46)

Is this right approach?

Comment: It's on the right lines, but not quite right. With Lookup, you can either have a rectangular array for the lookup (like A3:C46), or a vector for the lookup (like A3:A46) and another vector for the return array (like C3:C46). In the first case it will assume that the return value is in the right-most column (Column C), which is what you want. Lookup uses approximate match - either an exact match, or the next smaller value in the list - and assumes the lookup values are in order - which yours are. See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lookup-function-446d94af-663b-451d-8251-369d5e3864cb